# How to get the common array value in two array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array. I want to get the common value which have both aray indexing value is same.

Check my code-

```
$arr1 = array(0=>5,1=>7, 2=>9, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>8, 6=>7, 7=>0, 8=>1);


$arr2 = array(0=>7,1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>5, 4=>9, 5=>8, 6=>5, 7=>0, 8=>6);
```

I want to like-

```
array(
   5=>8
   7=>0
)
```

And there is `$arr2` is a duplicate value name `5` i also want to get duplicate value from `$arr2`

```
array(
   3=>5
   6=>5
)
```

How to get the matching value and duplicate value of above two Array?

Comment: [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/array_intersect_assoc)?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php)

```
$arr1 = array(0=>5,1=>7, 2=>9, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>8, 6=>7, 7=>0, 8=>1);
$arr2 = array(0=>7,1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>5, 4=>9, 5=>8, 6=>5, 7=>0, 8=>6);

$arr = array_intersect_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/226788)

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(0=>5,1=>7, 2=>9, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>8, 6=>7, 7=>0, 8=>1);
$arr2 = array(0=>7,1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>5, 4=>9, 5=>8, 6=>5, 7=>0, 8=>6);

$arr = array_intersect_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($arr);

$duplicate=array(); $duplicateVirtual=[];

foreach($arr2 as $index=>$val)
{   
    if(in_array($val,$duplicateVirtual)){ $duplicate[$index]=$val; }
    $duplicateVirtual[]=$val;
}

print_r($duplicate);
```

You can even create a function to check for duplicate and pass array as variable.

***[DEMo](https://eval.in/226849)***